# I somehow made hidden (dot)files in home visible - how to undo?

Tags: 14.04, home-directory

I can see hidden file and folders in my home directory. How to restore normal settings?

[image: Hear a picture.]

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Home` folder and in `View` option untick `Show Hidden Files`

Or simply press `Ctrl+H`.

Comment: @BratislavIvanovic Glad it worked. You can mark this anser as "accepted" by clicking on tick mark.

Comment: Just noticed I never accepted this answer. also, jeez I used to be a noob lol

Comment: oh wait nvm this wasn't asked by me, I'm dumb

Answer (score 0):

If its enabled by default, go to `Edit > Preferences` and click the checkbox beside `Show hidden and backup files`.  If its just a temporary thing you do every once in a while by accident, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.

Comment: Both those options do the same thing...

Comment: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> Shows/Hides hidden files temporarily, and nautilus will revert to the default after closing and re-opening, whereas clicking the checkbox will change the default so that it is that way every time you open nautilus, but can still be changed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

Comment: Oh no, the <kbd> tag doesn't work in comments :0

Comment: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> is `ctrl`+`h`

Comment: Huh... It reverts every time I open Nautilus on my PC. Well, just another reason to justify my switching to Nemo...